# explanation needed for exceptions/classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Consider the following snippet:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;


namespace ForumLogins {
    public class VBULLETIN {

        HttpWebRequest request;


        public void ForumLogins(string url) {          
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        }
    }
}
```

According to MSDN the "Create" method can return 4 exceptions. Now I cant dissolve those exceptions.. because well otherwise the class wont function. But what should I do? Should I still wrap it in a try/catch block? and in the catch "throw a new exception".. or let the person who implments this class handle the exceptions?

Cuz this is a constructor .. and I guess constructors arnt really supposed to fail?

Comment: What does "dissolve those exceptions" mean?

Comment: I don't see a constructor either.... the class is VBULLETIN, so its constructor would be VBULLETIN(), which isn't present.  WebRequest.Create isn't a constructor, its a static method.

Comment: The real WTF is that the class name is all uppercase. C# is not COBOL, thanks.

Comment: Jeez, sorry about that../ will name it to lower case, and make the constructor the right name lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your constructor can fail, then you should probably let the person who implements the class handle the errors. Just be sure to document the fact that it might fail so they know to try/catch.

On a related note, constructors should never fail. =)

Instead, put the logic that can possibly fail into a "Go()" method. That way you can instantiate a real class, but put a try/catch around segments of the code, and still reference the object outside of the try-catch block later. Just my $.02.

Comment: If you regard the task of a constructor to initialize an object (especially an immutable one) to a consistent state, and that depends on constructor arguments, then in general it IS possible for a constructor to fail. Hiding that fact by weakening the contract only defers the pain.

Comment: Let me restate for clarification:

A constructor should not be prone to failure. =) If there more than an outside chance that it might fail (i.e. out of memory error) but a solid probability (i.e. a lost network connection), then it is good practice to put that code in it's own method.

Answer (score 1):

What you do depends on the role of the code. If this is a library that your going to share I'd recommend you wrap all exceptions and rethrow meaningful exceptions for your library. This will help you achieve implenentation encapsulation.

For example

```
try
{
   if (string.isNullOrEmpty(url))
   {
      //This will stop the arugment null exception and you can throw a meaningful message
   } 
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
}
catch(SecurityException sex)
{
   //Can't handle this but maybee you can provide more information about how to configure security here...

     throw new YourCustomerException(msg,sex); //It's good practice to put the current exception in the inner exception
}
```

If your not building a component and this is your application then I recommend you somewhere along the stack catch the error, and log it.

Also this isn't a constructor your calling a Factory method on WebRequest called Create.

Comment: It's for a friend. And I will be posting this on the internet for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this code isn't the exact code you're going to be using, so I'm trying to answer your question based on what I can work out you're trying to ask.

I would recommend where possible, you handle the exception. If that's not possible, I think in your case the best approach would be to wrap the WebRequest.Create exception as the InnerException and rethrow it. That keeps the abstraction, while still making more detail available if necessary. Probably along the lines of this:

```
try{
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    throw new ForumLoginException(e);
}
```

Comment: I, unfornately, don't have time to inherit my own exceptions. But I will keep this in mind.

THANKYOU!

Comment: Creating an exception takes 2 mins;-)